# Encryption of image files on Android -- Cipher(Output|Input)Stream problems

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to encrypt image files on Android with password based encryption. To save the encrypted image I just do this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(thumbnailFile);
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, encryptCipher);
Bitmap thumbnail = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm2, 140, 140, true);
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, cos);
```

and to read it, this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, decryptCipher);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cis);
```

but the Bitmap ends up as null.  The code works when I bypass the encryption; that is when I use the File(Input|Output)Streams rather than the Cipher(Input|Output)streams.

My Ciphers are created as follows:

```
public void initCiphers(char password[]) {

PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec;
PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec;
SecretKeyFactory keyFac;

byte[] salt = {
   (byte)0xc7, (byte)0x73, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x8c,
   (byte)0x7e, (byte)0xc8, (byte)0xee, (byte)0x99
};
int count = 20;
pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count);          
pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
try {
    keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");    
    encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
    decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);       
} catch (Exception e) { 
    Log.v("tag", e.toString()); 
}
```

I don't get any exceptions.

There is obviously some problem with using Cipher(Output|Input)Streams with the android functions for encoding and/or decoding images, but since those functions are opaque and there are no exceptions, its hard to know what it is. I suspect it has to do with padding or flushing. Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Also -- if I use NullCipher as my Cipher it works.

Comment: Since PBEwithMD5andDES uses CBC mode with PKCS5Padding, it could be that Bitmap.compress is flushing its OutputStream at some point prior to closing the stream. Ordinarily this would not create a problem, but with a CipherOutputStream using a padding cipher, it would cause extra padding bytes to be inserted in the output. I supposed I could try to find the the source code for Bitmap.compress, to see if this is in fact what is happening ...

Comment: how u resolved your issue

Comment: @MatthewFleming did you manage to fix the issue? Would be great if you could share the solution.

Comment: Can you help me as well

Comment: @MatthewFleming it would be great help. Because I'm working on the same thing.

Comment: What is thumbnailFile and f in your code @MatthewFleming

Answer (score 3):

When writing to a CipherOutputStream, make sure you `close()` the stream after writing the data (and not closing the underlying stream before it). Closing makes sure the right padding is added. A `flush()` alone is not enough here.

Also, I would advise to not use DES for new protocols - preferred nowadays is AES.

Comment: This was the right answer for me! call `flush()` and `close()` after writing to the `CipherOutputStream`

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass CipherOutputStream or even just OutputStream, and just override the flush() method to do nothing.