# Android: Simple way to "encrypt" an Image

Tags: java, android, encryption, bitmap

I'm looking for a simple way to hide the contents of an image on Android. I don't need any high security encryption, I just need a way to hide the contents from the human eye (not dedicated machines).

What I want is:

- Encryption: input an image, output an image where the original content cannot be seen
- Decryption: input the "encrypted" image, output the original input.

I've tried to modify the pixel stream of the Bitmap by storing the sum of two previous pixels in the third pixel and set one of the previous pixels to a random number, but with this method the main shapes of the image are still visible.

I also tried to get the byte array of the bitmap and XOR the single bytes like so:

```
    Bitmap src = ((BitmapDrawable)original.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    src.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream2.toByteArray();
    byte[] encrByte = new byte[byteArray.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < encrByte.length; i++) {
        encrByte[i] = byteArray[i] ^ 5;
    } 
    Bitmap bmpDecr = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encrByte, 0, encrByte.length);
```

but that destroyed the image.

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve a behavior like this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to XOR it with a counter and wrap around when you reach 256.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526612/encryption-of-image-files-on-android-cipheroutputinputstream-problems). Its not quite what you want, but should work.